# T-SQL find record and allow for nulls

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
    [Id]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Column1]   VARCHAR (3)   NULL,
    [Column2]   VARCHAR (2)   NULL,
    [Column3]   VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [TableCon] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Column1] ASC, [Column2] ASC, [Column3] ASC)
);
```

My table will allow for null values in Columns(1-3), but each record will be unique based on those three values. Then I would have a function `GetID(c1, c2, c3)` which would return either the Id or no value

I know that I know that this will not work:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 = @c1
AND Column2 = @c2
AND Column3 = @c3
```

So how would I write something like this?

Comment: _why_ will it not work?  What input would give you the wrong output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `null` don't return `true` when compared with the `=` operator, you'd have to check for them explicitly with the `IS NULL` operator:

```
SELECT Id
FROM   Table1
WHERE  ((Column1 = @c1) OR (Column1 IS NULL AND @c1 IS NULL)) AND
       ((Column2 = @c2) OR (Column2 IS NULL AND @c2 IS NULL)) AND
       ((Column3 = @c3) OR (Column3 IS NULL AND @c3 IS NULL))
```

Comment: ... or to make it terse, you can use the COALESCE function.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking I would need a CASE or IF but the `Column1 IS NULL AND @c1 IS NULL` is that part I was missing. I'm so messed up on allergy meds right now I can't even spell my name correctly so I missed something so obvious.